How to skip a directory when downloading with wget?
I want to download a website with wget in Linux that have the following 'structure':
sssssssssss.com/things/summer/tables/books/
There is a directory in the directory 'summer', named 'sport'.
I want to download the whole website without this subdirectory 'sport'.
How should wget command look like? I know that it should use some arguments from the section 'Directory Options' of wget man-page,
(--cut-dirs=number
Ignore number directory components.  This is useful for getting a fine-grained control over the directory where recursive retrieval will be saved.
       Take, for example, the directory at ftp://ftp.xemacs.org/pub/xemacs/.  If you retrieve it with -r, it will be saved locally under ftp.xemacs.org/pub/xemacs/.  While the -nH
       option can remove the ftp.xemacs.org/ part, you are still stuck with pub/xemacs.  This is where --cut-dirs comes in handy; it makes Wget not "see" number remote directory
       components.  Here are several examples of how --cut-dirs option works.

               No options        -> ftp.xemacs.org/pub/xemacs/
               -nH               -> pub/xemacs/
               -nH --cut-dirs=1  -> xemacs/
               -nH --cut-dirs=2  -> .

               --cut-dirs=1      -> ftp.xemacs.org/xemacs/
               ...

       If you just want to get rid of the directory structure, this option is similar to a combination of -nd and -P.  However, unlike -nd, --cut-dirs does not lose with
       subdirectories---for instance, with -nH --cut-dirs=1, a beta/ subdirectory will be placed to xemacs/beta, as one would expect.)

but how the command should look like exactly in this case?
